# Debug rails project in RadRadils

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, radrails

How can I debug a rails project in RadRails?

I would like to put a breakpoint in my code, start the server from the Command prompt (`rails server`) and for example when I click a button on my web page, I would like to get to that line with the breakpoint if it is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using RailsPanel and Better Errors for it. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel?view=asciicast) is a railscast for the same.